# stderr: "Primary script unknown", request: "GET /data HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", "File not found from" while access from the web

Tags: nginx, php

When trying to access through the web I getting "File not found"
Nginx with php7.2-fpm on Centos 7

The full error from `/var/log/nginx/nginx.error` is:

> 2018/12/31 10:20:01 [error] 27963#0: *6478 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.199.61.10, server: unicorn.typical.blue, request: "GET /data HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "unicorn.typical.blue"

My `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/unicorn.typical.blue.conf` here:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name unicorn.typical.blue;
# enforce https
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name unicorn.typical.blue;

# Use Mozilla's guidelines for SSL/TLS settings
# https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
# NOTE: some settings below might be redundant
ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/unicorn_cert_chain.crt";
ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/unicorn.typical.blue.key";

# Add headers to serve security related headers
# Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
# topic first.
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
# includeSubDomains; preload;";
#
# WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
# the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
# will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
# in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
# could take several months.
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

# Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

# Path to the root of your installation
root /var/www/unicorn.typical.blue;

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
# Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
#rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
#rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

# The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
# Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
# rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;

location = /.well-known/carddav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
}
location = /.well-known/caldav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
}

# set max upload size
client_max_body_size 512M;
fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

# Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

# Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
# This module is currently not supported.
#pagespeed off;

location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
}

location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
    deny all;
}
location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    #Avoid sending the security headers twice
    fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
    fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
    fastcgi_pass php-handler;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_request_buffering off;
}

location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
    try_files $uri/ =404;
    index index.php;
}

# Adding the cache control header for js and css files
# Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
    # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
    # have those duplicated to the ones above)
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
    # this topic first.
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    #
    # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
    # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
    # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
    # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
    # could take several months.
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

    # Optional: Don't log access to assets
    access_log off;
}

location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
    access_log off;
}
}
```

My `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is that:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  your_server_ip;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the file: `/var/www/unicorn.typical.blue/index.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists, and also index.html exists

Comment: Oh, there was an error in directory name mistyped "unicron" instead..